# Get all date from month - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two parameters  MONTH and YEAR,  how get all date?

Eg. YEAR = 2021, MONTH = 8

```
Date
------
01.08.2021
02.08.2021
.....
31.08.2021
```

Comment: As long as "Date" is stored as a date datatype EXTRACT(month from DATE) = 8 and EXTRACT(year FROM DATE) = 2021 should do it. Where DATE is the name of your field, which hopefully isn't DATE.

Comment: Please, show your current query and describe what is wrong with it. Did you try [`to_date('202108', 'yyyymm')`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html) and [`last_day(some_date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAST_DAY.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  dt + level - 1 as date_
from    (select to_date(to_char(:year , 'fm0000') || 
                        to_char(:month, 'fm00'), 'yyyymm') as dt from dual)
connect by level <= add_months(dt, 1) - dt
;
```

This is almost the same as MT0's answer, with a few minor differences and one that is not entirely minor.

The `to_date` function assumes a default of first day of the month, so it is not necessary to explicitly concatenate `'01'` to the year and month (although perhaps doing so makes the code easier to read for beginner programmers). In my opinion, that's just a matter of taste.

I separated the computation of the first day of the month into a subquery. No worries, the optimizer will merge it into the outer query, so there is no efficiency cost - but the code will be easier to maintain.

The non-trivial difference is in the `connect by` clause. Even though mathematically the formula is equivalent to

```
dt + level - 1 < add_months(dt, 1)
```

or, better (still equivalent!)

```
dt + level <= add_months(dt, 1)
```

in terms of processing they are not equivalent. If written in the form above (previous line of code), for each value of `level`, the runtime will perform a date arithmetic calculation followed by a date comparison.

On the other hand, by solving the inequality for `level` (as I did in my query), the date calculation is performed just once (rather than once for every row), and the comparison is simply `level <=`  some calculated number.

Perhaps in this problem "efficiency" plays no role, but as a matter of good coding, we should "solve for `level`" whenever possible, for the reason I just gave.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of recursive CTEs, because they are standard SQL.  In Oracle, you can use one like this:

```
with cte(dte) as (
      select to_date('2020' || '8', 'YYYYMM')  -- the two parameters are '2020' and '8'
      from dual
      union all
      select dte + interval '1' day
      from cte
      where dte < last_day(dte)
     )
select * 
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=09b07ce40bd9559d3c20b250f583f54e) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you pass in the bind variables `:year` and `:month`, then you can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(:year, 'FM0000') || TO_CHAR(:month, 'FM00') || '01',
         'YYYYMMDD'
       ) + LEVEL - 1 AS "Date"
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY
       TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(:year, 'FM0000') || TO_CHAR(:month, 'FM00') || '01',
         'YYYYMMDD'
       ) + LEVEL - 1
       <
       ADD_MONTHS(
         TO_DATE(
           TO_CHAR(:year, 'FM0000') || TO_CHAR(:month, 'FM00') || '01',
           'YYYYMMDD'
         ),
         1
       )
```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d700af/464)*